# CompareTo versus Equals! compares strings or objects?

Tags: java, string, compareto, string-comparison

Fast question

I am comparing a String, should I use equals or compareTo?
because I though equals distinguish 2 objects of type String
and not just their value...

which may cause problems since:

```
String a = new String("lol");
String b = new String("lol");
```

are two different objects even if they have the same value?

Whats exactly difference between equals and compareTo implementations in terms of performance and precision?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Strings: compareTo() vs. equals()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551235/java-strings-compareto-vs-equals)

Comment: funny how i get -6rep while the other guy gets +41rep

Comment: Hi, you can also check this link here http://www.leepoint.net/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all `==` compares the references to see if the two objects are the same (so `==` is on the object).

Then `String.equals()` verify the equality of the content of two strings while `String.compareTo()` seek the difference of the content of two strings.

So the two following tests are equivalent:

```
String str = "my string";

if ( str.equals("my second string")) {/*...*/}
if ( str.compareTo("my second string")==0) {/*...*/}
```

But, since `String.equals` is making a reference check first, it's safe when used against `null`, while `String.compareTo` will throws a `NullPointerException`:

```
String str = "my string";

if ( str.equals(null)) {/* false */}
if ( str.compareTo(null) {/* NullPointerException */}
```

Answer (score 12):

Did you try it?

```
String a = new String("foo");
String b = new String("foo");

System.out.println(a == b); // false
System.out.println(a.equals(b)); // true
System.out.println(a.compareTo(b)); // 0
```

Comment: so whats the difference? between using equals and compareTo?

Comment: yes, but Im confuse... How can I compare if two objects Strings are different?

Comment: you use compare to find out ordering between elements, equals to determine if they are more or less the 'same' by their contents. == is used to test if  the **references** point to the same object. All this is very easy to find in the api!

Comment: @NavySeal [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) tests the values of two objects to see if they are the same. [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) tests the values of two objects to see if one is "greater than" the other. In the case of `String`s, it compares the lexicographical order of the characters.

Comment: this is one of those doubts where everything looks like the same but small differences matter

Comment: @NavySeal - yea, this is one of those situations where you have to slow down and ... THINK ... :-)

Answer (score -3):

```
    String a = new String("lol");
    String b = new String("lol");

    System.out.println(a == b); // false. It checks references of both sides operands and we have created objects using new operator so references would not be same and result would be false.
    System.out.println(a.equals(b)); // true checks Values and values are same
    System.out.println(a.compareTo(b)); //  checks for less than, greater than or equals. Mainly used in sortings.
```