# java Float: == equals compareTo

Tags: java, equals, compareto

I have 2 questions.

1) I was told that when comparing two `Float` or `Double` data, use `compareTo` instead of `equals`. I don't know the reason. Is there any example that shows where using `equals` will lead something wrong?

2) See this code:

```
  float f2=(float)1.123450;
  Float f3=new Float(1.123450);

  System.out.println(f3==f2);   // result is true
```

I think using `==` means the two data point to the same memory address. But do `f3` and `f2` have the same address? Doesn't `new Float(...)` create a new space?

Comment: somewhat relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551235/java-strings-compareto-vs-equals?rq=1

Comment: From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#compareTo(java.lang.Float)): " the natural ordering of Float objects imposed by this method [`compareTo`] is consistent with `equals`."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If both arguments were reference types, then `==` would test memory locations. However, if one of the arguments to `==` (or `!=`) is numeric and the other is convertible to numeric (using unboxing), then the comparison is done by comparing numerical values after unboxing. So the comparison in this case is done on the basis of the floating point values (which in this case are identical). See the [Java Language Specification §15.21.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1) for details.

Note, however, that `Float.NaN == Float.NaN` is `false`.

Comment: Also note that generally speaking, you want to compare two floats/doubles by seeing if they're very close, not if they're exactly equal. This is due to rounding errors that floats can accumulate, especially when a decimal number can't be exactly represented as a float (e.g. 0.1).

Comment: @yshavit - Yes, this is a very good point that's gotten lost in discussing the differences between `equals`, `compareTo`, and `==` for a single value. (However, I see now that Peter changed his response to focus on that exact point.)

Answer (score 8):

Generally speaking `==` is fine unless you need to handling rounding or arithmetic errors in which case compareTo() won't help you much.

If you want to compare two doubles within an error you can use

```
if (Math.abs(a - b) < ERR) // within error.
```

or a relative error

```
if (Math.abs(a - b) < ERR * (Math.abs(a) + Math.abs(b))/2) // within error.
```

or within rounding whether the factor is often a power of ten like 10000 means to 4 decimal places.

```
if (Math.round(a * factor) == Math.round(b * factor)) // within a multiple
```

Comment: From [the docs for Float.equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#equals(java.lang.Object)): _"If `f1` and `f2` both represent `Float.NaN`, then the equals method returns `true`, even though `Float.NaN==Float.NaN` has the value `false`."_

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you have two (primary) types,

1. Primitives
2. Reference

   Primitive types are considered primitives if and only if they are of type `double`, `float`, `int`, `long`, and so on.

   Reference types are any type that uses an "Object" to store data. When you are creating in class, you're really creating a reference type "in disguise." Some examples of reference types are `String`, `Double`, `Integer`, and so on.

   So, as far as types go, when you compare `float x` to `Float y`, you're really comparing two different types!

   In Java, the `==`'s operator, most of the time, to compare only objects of equal type. Sometimes, however, the language will permit comparison of other types, such as `x == y` in the case that `x` is a primitive and `y` is a reference type (as defined above).

   When the comparison between `x` and `y` is performed an operation called boxing and unboxing is performed. But to understand boxing, you have to understand the difference between primitive types and reference types in terms of memory semantics. (Don't let that scare you!)

   Primitive types are stored in a memory location called the stack, which is fast and not very flexible in terms of fragmented access. It's pretty easy.

   Reference types are different though: when a reference type is **instantiated** using the `new` operator (which is called implicitly when doing `Float x = <something>;` -- that is, `Float x = <something>;` is turned into `Float x = new Float(<something>);`) So when a `Float` or other reference type is instantiated, the object is created and stored on the heap, but the pointer to that object (which is on the heap) is stored in the stack.

   This means that in order to retrieve the value that is stored in `x`, the computer must use the address stored on the stack, and go to that memory address in the heap.

   We use the heap to store reference types because the stack is not very good at something called "dynamic memory allocation," which is where memory is allocated and deallocated without concern to other objects around it.

   Now for boxing and unboxing:

   Boxing (also called wrapping) is the process of taking a primitive type object and storing it as a reference type (so `float x` becomes `Float x`), so that those two objects are the **same** type. (It's kind of like wrapping a christmas present in paper) So, behind the scenes, `Integer k = 6` is a kind of boxing (autoboxing)

   Unboxing on the other hand is the opposite of unboxing, so you can call it unwrapping. Unboxing takes a "boxed" object and takes it from a reference type back to a primitive type, so the statements can work without too much hassle.:

   `Integer k = 6; //Boxing`

   `int m = k; //Unboxing`

   What this really means, in terms of your question: in the code that you posted, autoboxing and unboxing occurred, which made the statement valid. The JVM was smart enough to do what you meant -- but that doesn't mean you should make a regular habit of it, because boxing and unboxing can have a serious impact on the performance of your code!

   Also, if both `x` and `y` were `Float` types, you'd be comparing references!

   Good Luck!