# Object comparison using equality & comparable interface

Tags: java

Could anyone please explain me whether there's any difference in the codes below when comparing objects and more specifically their values.

Code 1

```
x.equals(y)
```

Code 2

```
x.compareTo(y) == 0
```

Are the codes above interchangeable. What's the difference if any?

Comment: `It is strongly recommended, but not strictly required that (x.compareTo(y)==0) == (x.equals(y)). Generally speaking, any class that implements the Comparable interface and violates this condition should clearly indicate this fact. The recommended language is "Note: this class has a natural ordering that is inconsistent with equals."`

Comment: _"The natural ordering for a class C is said to be consistent with equals if and only if e1.compareTo(e2) == 0 has the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 of class C. Note that null is not an instance of any class, and **e.compareTo(null)** should throw a **NullPointerException** even though **e.equals(null)** returns **false**."_

Answer (score 2):

From [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

> **It is strongly recommended, but not strictly required that
>   (x.compareTo(y)==0) == (x.equals(y)). Generally speaking, any class
>   that implements the Comparable interface and violates this condition
>   should clearly indicate this fact.** The recommended language is "Note:
>   this class has a natural ordering that is inconsistent with equals."

As @ZouZou mention

> The natural ordering for a class C is said to be consistent with
>   equals if and only if e1.compareTo(e2) == 0 has the same boolean value
>   as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 of class C. **Note that null is not
>   an instance of any class, and e.compareTo(null) should throw a
>   NullPointerException even though e.equals(null) returns false.**

That means they are not interchangable.

An example where this happen in java api is in [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Test{
 public static void main(String args[])  {

       BigDecimal big = BigDecimal.ZERO;
       BigDecimal zero  = new BigDecimal("0.00");

       System.out.println("Compare "+ (big.compareTo(zero) == 0) ); //prints true
       System.out.println("Equals "+big.equals(zero)); // prints false      
 } 
}
```

Comment: One notable example of a class where `equals()` is inconsistent with `compareTo()` is [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Comment: And a reminder that if you are overriding equals(Object) make sure you also override hashCode() to be consistent with equals. ["If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode())

Comment: @Victor good advice but it's not related to this question.

Answer (score 1):

[`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) doesn't always make sense, sometimes the *objects* **cannot** be logically ordered.
Also note that `equals` always exists, since it's defined in `Object` class.

It's a good practice to always haven [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method when you have `compareTo`, and they should be consistent.

Also you might want to have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551235/java-strings-compareto-vs-equals).

Answer (score 0):

It is not interchangeable  for Strings.

```
x.equals((String)null)  returns false
```

Code 2

```
x.compareTo((String)null) == 0 // throws a NullPointerException
```

See here:[Java Strings: compareTo() vs. equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551235/java-strings-compareto-vs-equals)