# Which method to check if dates are the same is better?

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

[getTime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#getTime()) method compares Unix times of dates. I don't know how [compareTo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#compareTo(java.util.Date)) method works. Which one is better (faster) and why?

```
Date date1 = ...
Date date2 = ...

//METHOD 1
if(date1.getTime() == date2.getTime()) {
...
}

//METHOD 2
if(date1.compareTo(date2) == 0) {
...
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551235/java-strings-compareto-vs-equals

Comment: I think in your case it doesn't make any difference. Comparison of two longs is a simple enough operation available in almost all CPUs currently in use on the planet. I would expect that the == variant is slightly faster since compareTo also bothers to compute the kind of (un|)equality (-1,0,1). But remember early optimization is the root of all evil. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First method uses one comparison, second method uses on average 3 comparisons(2 from compareTo and 1 from your code)

Lets see sources

```
public int compareTo(Date date) {
    if (milliseconds < date.milliseconds) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (milliseconds == date.milliseconds) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Premise: you wrote that "getTime() method compares Unix times of dates". This is not correct, since that function **returns the amount of time as an integer**. Hence, you can rely on the first method, that's just a numerical comparison. You won't find nothing faster than this:

```
if(date1.getTime() == date2.getTime()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I didn't write that getTime() compares anything. I wrote that this method using getTime() compares Unix times.

Comment: Yes you did, literally. "getTime() method compares Unix times of dates".

Comment: No, I didn't. I meant method as a way to do it, not as function of Date class.