# Relationship between equals and compareTo methods

Tags: java, equals, comparable, compareto

```
public abstract class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit> {

   protected String name;
   protected int size;
   protected Fruit(String name, int size){
      this.name = name;
      this.size = size;
   }
   public int compareTo(Fruit that){
       return  this.size < that.size ? - 1:
       this.size == that.size ? 0 : 1;
   }
}
class Apple extends Fruit {
   public Apple(int size){ super("Apple",size);
}
public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Apple a1 = new Apple(1); Apple a2 = new Apple(2);

      List<Apple> apples = Arrays.asList(a1,a2);
      assert Collections.max(apples).equals(a2);
   }
}
```

What is relationship between equals() and compareTo() methods in this program?

I know that when class Fruit implements interface Comparable it must contains in its body definition of compareTo method but I don't understand what influence has this method on calling of: `Collections.max(apples).equals(a2)`.

And from where compareTo takes the value of "that.size"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Strings: compareTo() vs. equals()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551235/java-strings-compareto-vs-equals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your `compareTo` method compares `Fruit`s based on their `size`. This is a custom implementation.
- `Collections.max` will invoke `compareTo` a number of times related to the size of your collection, to infer the `max` item in the collection, hence `compareTo` is invoked.
- `Object#equals` will be invoked when invoking `equals` in your example, as it is not overridden in `Fruit`.
- The equality will be tested between the "largest" fruit in your collection, and the second `Apple` you declared, i.e. between the same `Apple` with size `2` in this case. It should return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

The `equals` and `compareTo` don't influence each other in this code. The `compareTo` method is determining which element is returned as `max`, and then the code checks if that element is equal to `a2`.

In other words, it's checking if `a2` is the largest apple, because the comparison made by `compareTo` checks only for size.

> And from where compareTo takes the value of "that.size"?

`size` is a field in the `Fruit` class. In `compareTo`, both `this` and `that` are instances of `Fruit`, and therefore, both of them have a `size` field.